# Bullet Lists after Paragraph in Python Docstring sometimes don't work with sphinx and numpydoc

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, numpydoc

Documenting a Python module using the [numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/doc/HOWTO_DOCUMENT.rst.txt) style and generating html documentation using [sphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/index.html) and the [numpydoc](https://github.com/numpy/numpydoc) extension, I stumbled upon a bug (or feature?) regarding bulleted lists.

```
In reStructuredText (and sphinx/numpydoc), a single-lined paragraph
    - with an immediately following
    - bullet list
    - is allowed,

but if you have a "long" paragraph,
which may be spanning several lines,
    - a following bullet list
    - results in an `ERROR: Unexpected indentation`.

With a blank line added between the "long" paragraph, which again
may span multiple lines, and the following list,

    - bullet lists
    - work fine again.
```

According to the [reStructuredText reference](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#bullet-lists), bullet lists require an empty line before and after them.

**Therefore I'd like to know:** Why does the fist version work (while it shouldn't), and what is so different to the (not working) second version?

---

#### Edit:

In generated html the first and the last version differ in appearance. If the look of the bullet list *without* a leading empty line is desired (less space in html), a quickfix could be

```
to escape every line break by a backslash.\
This way there's effectively only a single long line,
    - which allows bullet lists
    - even after long paragraphs.
```

This avoids the parsing error, but still does not answer the question of *why*  :-)

Answer (score 1):

The first example is actually a [definition list](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#definition-lists):

A definition list consists of a

```
term: 
  a one-line word or phrase, and a
   
definition:
  a block indented relative to the term.
```

There may be no blank line between a term line and a definition block (this distinguishes definition lists from block quotes).
The definition block may consist of any [body elements](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/doctree.html#body-elements)
(including lists of any type).

The second example fails, because a term cannot be distributed over two lines and a paragraph cannot be followed by an indented block without separating empty line.

The third example is actually a paragraph with a [block-quote](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#block-quotes) containing a nested list. This is usually not what you mean and it causes the list in the output to be indented too much (cf. [Docutils FAQ](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/FAQ.html#how-should-i-mark-up-lists)).